# Adjusting height of one of the Divs with only CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this shape  [image].

My current CSS gives me shape like this [image].

The only thing I'm stuck at is reducing height of the first grey bar. All the 3 grey bars have same class (.ward) and I cannot use any javascript or inline styling to adjust height of the first rectangle(ward). How do I update height of first ward?

Here is my HTML snippet:

```
<div id="stem"></div>
<div id="wards">
    <div class="ward"></div>
    <div class="ward"></div>
    <div class="ward"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried taking the !important off of the height of .ward? Not sure why that's there anyways, but it may be interfering with any div-specific styling you're trying to apply.

Comment: Note that you should not use !important except in troubleshooting.  It will override normal css rules.

Comment: The code is still in works so its not very clean. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add this css selector if will only apply to the first ward class.

```
.ward:first-child{
    height: 6px !important
}
```

More information on the first child selector -
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

A good list of all the selectors you can use -
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

*If I understand your question correctly. adding another class isn't breaking the rule of inline styling(especially if you are doing this in a separate CSS file).* Why don't you try giving the first "ward" it's own CSS class.

Such as

`<div id="stem"></div>
    <div id="wards">
        <div class="specialward"></div>
        <div class="ward"></div>
        <div class="ward"></div>
    </div>`

AND

```
.ward {
        /*border: 1px solid #666666;*/
        background-color: #666666;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        opacity: 1;
        width: 7px;
        height: 12px!important;
        margin-right: -8px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

.specialward {
        /*border: 1px solid #666666;*/
        background-color: #666666;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        opacity: 1;
        width: 7px;
        height: 10px!important;
        margin-right: -8px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

If you're question is more along the lines of; "Can I alter This div, using this class that the two other use. However the attributes of the same class needs to be different than the other two". I don't believe you can.

Hope this helps.